# What is the time complexity of sorting a list of already known elements?

Tags: sorting, time-complexity

If I had a list of unknown e.g. real numbers between 0 and 100, then I know that the best (average case) time complexity achievable is O(nlogn). My question is, what if the elements that exist in the list are predetermined to come from a finite set?

E.g., if the list may only contain *integers* between 0 and 100, can't we do better? Or for example if we are sorting a string containing only English characters.

A more extreme example is a list containing either 0s or 1s (only): I could easily think of an O(n) method.

The O(n) method for sorting a list of only 0s and 1s could work like this:

Count the number of zeros and ones in the list (O(n))
then create a new list = [0]*(# of zeros) + [1]*(# of ones)

Comment: Have you considered Radix sort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right in your reasoning.

You are basically describing a variation of [Counting Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort). If the range is constant, then you can indeed achieve a time complexity of *O(n)* to sort them. In general, the time complexity of counting sort is *O(n + k)*, where *k* is the range of your elements. Another variation is [Radix Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort).

More generally, the theoretical lower bound of *O(n log n)*, that you have probably heard of, holds for [comparison based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort) sorting algorithms. Essentially, it's a stronger requirement. Your algorithm for a binary range, and counting sort, are not comparison based, which is why we can achieve better time complexity.

Comment: Worth mentioning the time/space tradeoff of counting and radix sort. For example, if you are sorting 64-bit integers (rather than arbitrary-precision integers like Python `int` values), there are "only" `2**64` values to consider, so you could sort them in O(n) time... *if* you have the memory for the required `2**64`-element array of counts.